# We have a blog, who wants to write a post?

Tags: discussion, blog

After [discussing this with the community](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/should-we-have-an-associated-blog)--and then bringing it up to the Stack Exchange people--we now have an official community blog: [bicycles.blogoverflow.com](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/). As you can see, there's nothing there just yet.

We'll be adding accounts for those people who volunteered to write posts, and you'll get notifications to the email addresses associated with your Stack Exchange account on Bicycles. Once you're added, please feel free to write a post and submit it. Let's get a few posts up so we have something to talk about.

If anyone else wants to give this a try, please give us a shout. For now, frieheit and myself are the blog Admins, although that will, I'm sure, change over time.

Anyone have an idea for a post? You have a favorite question on the site and want to talk about it? Go ahead and write a blog post, or maybe tell us about the idea here to hash it out.

Remember, blog posts are not pages on this site. They can be anything related to bicycles: The story of your latest bike ride, a rant about how people won't shut up about the Tour de France (or how people don't care about it, those Philistines!), a blurb about your favorite bicycle website (here's [mine](http://www.crazyguyonabike.com/)), whatever you like. The only requirements are that it be interesting to *somebody*.

Comment: Okay, have added @Joe Bronikowski, @zenbike, and @ʍǝɥʇɐɯ but I got error messages. If anyone didn't get an activation or confirmation email, please tell me and I'll look into the problem. (Do any of you have active blog accounts on other SE sites?)

Comment: I didn't get any email; no pre-existing blog account.

Comment: @Joe - You may have an email now.

Comment: @Joe - There's a discussion on chat if you're around.

Comment: @Neil, got the login info, and will duplicate next news article on bikes.se blogsite.

Comment: @zenbike - Is that post of yours about the TdF good to go? I'll publish it if so.

Comment: @Neil: Yep. Feel free to edit layout or proofread, but I'm good with it.

Comment: There were some line breaks missing inside the paragraphs, I tweaked some punctuation. Nice post, I [published it](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/its-tour-time/).

Comment: ...would it be more useful if the blog posts referred to questions in bicycle.SE? Like you could make a post that summarizes information -- or better connects information that labels currently do not do. Like one could write a post about some problem during touring and how it was solved. I am sure I could do many such posts because many of my questions are a bit like evolution: problem, question, problem, question,...

Comment: @hhh: Posts like that would certainly be useful. Would you like to be set up as a blog contributor?

Comment: freiheit: sure -- I could start making some sense to the chaos of questions out there. For me, the blog contributing will then be more like re-organizing/structuring stuff so I won't write the post unless I feel it would be every important to stress some issue.

Comment: @hhh: email invite to be a blog contributor on its way.  Had to add an extra "h" to the username, sorry about that. Username requirements have a 4-character minimum.

Comment: freiheit: well now I am called hhhh --- why don't they make regexes possible to names? h* would be much nicer :P I found some good ideas how to introduce some confusing topics. In Security.SE, they have some good layouts like [here](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/06/a-tour-of-password-questions-and-answers/), investigating.

Comment: People, please don't forget to comment on the posts. There's nothing like seeing lots of comments to make a poster feel wanted!

Comment: @hhh - I'm not completely clear on how this works in Wordpress, but you may be able to change your display name on the blog. In your profile edit screen, try typing hhh as your nickname, then choosing "hhh" from the menu just under it. (I tried it on mine and was able to change it to "blah".)

Comment: Nobody's written a post in over a week. Any chance someone could write one of these planned posts?

Answer (score 3):

I had an idea for a "weight loss and the newbie cyclist" post, about what I've learned about those two topics.  It will probably take a few days since I'm currently typing left-handed only (and I guess I owe another PPS on [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4366/is-it-harmful-to-shift-rd-while-climbing-standing) about a broken cog and a fractured elbow...)

Comment: Sounds like a good topic!

Comment: You should have an account now.

Comment: how's this going?

Comment: @Neil Fein - Whoops, just noticed my Inbox flag, just saw this.  I never did get any email inviting / describing how to create a blog post.  Of course I haven't put words to paper yet either.  If you can get me the authoring info I will commit to writing the post this weekend.

Comment: I think I see the problem, you have different email addresses on your meta and main account pages. We sent it to the one on the meta account. I'll try deleting you and re-adding you under the other one.

Comment: Had to add you as joebronikowski1 (with a "1" on the end) since joebronikowski is already "taken". Do you have the invite email now?

Comment: I should be using the same email on both, but I note the openid only shows on one.  I will have to let you know in a couple hours if I got the email - not home yet :-)

Comment: Still no email.  I did verify both main and specify the same email address, and I clicked on each and sent myself an email to verify no spam-blocking issues.

Comment: Will contact the SE Blog team, but before I do - Are you currently blogging on any other SE sites? If so, what email address did you use for that account?

Comment: Also, I just now tried adding you as an existing user; if it works, you should get an email. (I see you synced up your accounts, thanks.) Any luck?

Comment: Ok, got the email and got logged in.  Thanks!  Now I need to write something :-)

Answer (score 3):

It'll probably take a week or so to get to it...but a post on riding my first century of the year without agony...covering spring training and ride nutrition...

Comment: Blog invitation email on its way.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an open letter to Nottinghamshire police regarding the incident below, and I'd really like the opportunity to post it to the blog.

http://www.theguardian.com/environment/bike-blog/2013/aug/08/nottingham-police-cyclist-video

Comment: You're set up to be able to write blog posts. Log in here: http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/wp-admin/

Answer (score 1):

I took part in the World Naked Bike Ride earlier this year, I could do a write-up of that. Might take me a week or two to get round to it though.

Comment: I'd be happy to set you up as a blog contributor, but I need an email address and there's none in your profile.

Comment: Keep in mind, you can always write a short post with pictures, that'd be quicker. (Very, *very* carefully selected pictures.)

Comment: I've updated my profile. I'll have a look at what photos I've got...

Comment: @Tom77: invite to contribute to blog sent.

Answer (score 1):

I have a blog post in progress - which is great because I can save it as a draft and come back to it.

My topic is about cycling in London, why I like it and so forth. Might I suggest other contributors write about the reality of riding where they live, what to watch out for and so forth. Easiest topic there is, maybe a category will be needed for such posts.

@Neil Fein - can we add 'posts' b.t.w.?

Comment: I don't understand your question, you recently *did* add a post.

Comment: ...no, that is in progress. 'Draft' status is what I set it to - I always prefer to write + review my own stuff, usuially to make it shorterer and take out the tyypos.

Comment: Just keep your post in "draft" status, and we'll leave it alone until you change the status to "pending". (That's the cue for an admin to look at it and post it.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to write a blog post that would be an expanded version of [my answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4918/mountain-bike-in-usd-1-000-1200-range/4937#4937) to the question about how to choose the proper mountain bike.  If you'd allow it, though, may I do a short series of posts to expand more thoroughly on the components of mountain bikes.  Either way, I can probably submit something within the next two weeks.

Comment: You should have an email now with an invitation to open an account with the blog. When you submit a post as pending, please @reply myself or freiheit in chat (or here) and we'll proofread and publish your post. Looking forward to seeing your first post!

Comment: +1 for being awesome and encouraging me to contribute more to this online community.

Comment: Ready when you are... :)

Comment: When this is done, maybe you could later write about [that fixie you built](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4964/what-kind-of-handlebar-should-go-on-a-fixie-to-sell-it)? A build-to-selling-the-bike story could be really awesome. (And that's one drool-worthy bike.)

Comment: @NeilFein I'm working on it, I'm working on it. It's harder than I thought it would be. It's nowhere near as easy as a college essay because I just want to write something from the heart that I'm proud of and avoid sounding like an idiot or a tool.

Comment: Okay, sorry if I'm being a pest. :) If the post has specific problems, you could always ask freiheit or myself to have a look at it and make suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to be able to post on the blog about rides and the restoration I'm undertaking.

Comment: What's your email? I'll hook you up with a blog contributor account.

Comment: I don't like posting emails on open forums. Is there no private message feature on this site?

Comment: No, there isn't one. (The [Stack Exchange people have declined to implement this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/149375).) But you can contact me on my website, just go [here](http://neilfein.com/) and then click "contact Neil" on the left sidebar.

Comment: Or ask one of the mods to set you up with an account, since we can see the email addresses. Do an "@freiheit" in chat or just flag a post like this  with a custom message. Looks like Glenn's already taken care of, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to write for the blog as well. I have previous experience writing for a cycling blog ([shameless plug](http://www.AlbanyBicycleCoalition.com) as most bloggers are used to by now), but since I moved I haven't been writing there because I am now not connected to the city and therefore can only talk about things from a national perspective.

I would like to stretch my blogging muscles again though so I'd like to throw my hat in the ring.

Comment: Sure, [send me your email address](http://magnificentnose.com/contact/) and I'll set you up with a blog account. (I'm the editor on that website, that contact form sends stuff to me.)

Comment: Got your message, have send you an invite.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at a couple of the recent posts ("A great place to ride") I was thinking I might write up something about my cross-town commute:

http://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?msid=205985130044860903492.00046b74b5931db7ffe2f&msa=0&ll=49.301173,-123.0546&spn=0.061006,0.138016

I was thinking it might be interesting because it starts out going over this awful bridge:

http://images.drivebc.ca/bchighwaycam/pub/html/www/73.html

(Or, since they sometimes move the webcam, here's a picture showing the sidewalk I ride along.  As you go around the curve, before you get to the bridge itself where the railings start, you have an embankment on your left and a lovely curb on your right...)

[image]

I take the path on the left of the webcam... it's a long uphill grind, against traffic, lots of trucks kicking up dust, and for bikes to pass, one has to stop and hug the railing to make room.  (But there can be nice views from the apex of the bridge on a clear day.)

But after the bridge the ride is mostly very pleasant, going through residential neighborhoods just off the busy streets.  During bike-to-work-week, the bike traffic on the route is pretty amazing:

http://vancouver.ca/engsvcs/transport/cycling/bikeways/routes/adanac.htm

If this sounds like an acceptable post topic, **don't** set me up with an account yet.  I'd prefer to wait until bike-to-work-week (sometime in May) and I'm terrible for getting the actual writing done (I have a couple dozen almost-finished documents/posts/articles kicking around waiting to be finished) so I'd like to wait until I'm almost done, then I'll post again or @ someone when I'm ready.

Comment: Okay, let us know when you're ready. This sounds like a good post; I really wanna know how you get over that bridge.

Comment: Oops, I forgot that they sometimes swing that webcam around a bit.  The way it was pointing when I posted, you could see the sidewalk that I ride along.