# How to up the frequency of blog posts?

Tags: discussion, blog

It's been ten days since our last blog entry. The posts we've gotten have been quite good. Way to go, people!

While [enthusiasm was pretty high at first](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/should-we-have-an-associated-blog), now that it's time to actually write the posts, people aren't following through often enough to even get a post a week, let alone two or three.

**Can anyone think of a way to elicit posts from people, short of [bugging them in meta](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349/we-have-a-blog-who-wants-to-write-a-post) or in chat?**

**Anyone want to take the lead on coordinating this?** Anyone have ideas on how to keep the blog going? Perhaps we could set up a schedule or a calendar of who's posting when?

(We're not the only site that's having these problems, incidentally. Sci-fi/Fantasy

I *know* we've got some opinionated, interesting people here. Remember, blog posts don't need to be long, and if you have something long in mind, you can split it up into parts if you like. Anyone whose question has been closed... you can always turn that into a blog post!

---

**Edit:** Let me be absolutely clear about this - I'm *not* criticizing anybody who has or hasn't posted to the blog, and I apologize if this comes across that way. I just want to know what we can do to make it more attractive or easier to contribute.

---

**Update:** As per freiheit's answer, let's hold stuff in the queue and publish posts on Monday mornings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a schedule/calendar is a good plan.  We've actually had enough posts for one a week through another week from now, but we released (published) some very close together (right as soon as they were ready) and never kept any kind of cache of ready posts. There's always going to be some irregularity with when posts are *written*, sometimes a few in one week, sometimes a dry spell for a couple weeks. Better to make the release schedule more like a smooth one-a-week thing.

I think we should keep to a schedule, probably 1 post a week on Mondays.

If we happen to have an extra post or two in a week, wait to do anything with them. Most posts can sit around a week or three and still be just as relevant. Treat it as a queue and publish the oldest post in the queue sometime on Monday and leave the rest alone. Only jump the queue or release early if there's a timeliness aspect (such as [the launch blog post](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/bicycles-launched/) or zenbike's [Tour post](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/its-tour-time/)). And if we do have a post jump the queue because of timeliness, consider delaying everything else a week.

If we ever get to the point where the queue of ready posts is too big, we can start publishing 2 a week or alternate between 1-a-week and 2-a-week or something like that.

I'll try to write something (maybe about how car drivers should deal with cyclists), but given my own schedule it'd probably be ready for posting on August 28th at the earliest, and likely more like September 5th.

Comment: I agree that once a week would be great. Mondays sound fine, but right now we need people to write something, anything at all so we can publish it. But I like your idea about treating the submitted posts as a queue. It'd also make the need for posts more concrete.

Answer (score 1):

Can we make the blog a bit more visible? At the moment I think the only link to it is down at the bottom of the page in amongst a whole load of other stuff. Can we have a link at the top of the page too?

I will try and pull my finger out and actually write a blog post.

Comment: I'd love it if we could do that, but unfortunately, all we can do is either link to the blog with a system message, like we did when it launched. I'll bring this up on Meta.SO.

Comment: When there's a new post the `chat` link at the top is replaced with a `blog` link and a big exciting "new" badge next to it. For 24 hours.

Comment: I didn't even know there was a blog. Even after seeing this post I couldn't find it anywhere on the site. I think unless the blog is promoted more you're not going to get more posts.

Comment: Tom - scheduled your post.

Comment: Mac - You're quite correct. We need more on-site publicity.

Comment: @Mac - To address this issue, I just posted this on Meta.SO: [Per-site blog publicity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103149/per-site-blog-publicity).