# Moz Back, where is Moz? What happened to his account? Deleted? Why?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I noticed that Moz's answers are now with odd colour. Could someone explain what is happening? He has offered high quality answers and he is one of the most respected bicyclist on this network. Now for some reason, he is away. I always liked his style and answers -- now it is extremely hard to find them because I cannot see his profile anymore. Could someone help with this filtering problem with away-deleted users?

I feel this a bit sad if we really lost Moz. Then again, perhaps this site required too much energy from him -- so better for him to be Free. If you decided to free yourself, have fun! And big thanks for your contributions to the community, we appreciated it!

Moz back, where are you?

My feature-request is to get Mozes back. If it is impossible, I want better search over deleted users. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.moz.net.nz/

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Moz did come back: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/7044/

Answer (score 2):

> My feature-request is to get Mozes back. If it is impossible, I want better search over deleted users. Thank you.

Unfortunately, there's nothing we can do about this. @Moz has elected to [leave Stack Exchange](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/should-we-have-an-associated-blog/338#338) for his own reasons.